# Spark Streaming aggregation and filter in the same window

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I've a fairly easy task - events are coming in and I want to filter those with higher value than the average per group by key in the same window.
I think this this is the relevant part of the code:

```
val avgfuel = events
    .groupBy(window($"enqueuedTime", "30 seconds"), $"weatherCondition")    
    .agg(avg($"fuelEfficiencyPercentage") as "avg_fuel")    

val joined = events.join(avgfuel, Seq("weatherCondition"))
    .filter($"fuelEfficiencyPercentage" > $"avg_fuel")

val streamingQuery1 = joined.writeStream
    .outputMode("append").
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds")).
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation).
    .format("json").option("path", containerOutputLocation).start()
```

events is a DStream.
The problem is that I'm getting empty files in the output location.
I'm using Databricks 3.5 - Spark 2.2.1 with Scala 2.11

What have I done wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** a more complete code -

```
val inputStream = spark.readStream
  .format("eventhubs") // working with azure event hubs
  .options(eventhubParameters)
  .load()

val schema = (new StructType)    
      .add("id", StringType)
      .add("latitude", StringType)
      .add("longitude", StringType)
      .add("tirePressure", FloatType)
      .add("fuelEfficiencyPercentage", FloatType)
      .add("weatherCondition", StringType)

val df1 = inputStream.select($"body".cast("string").as("value")
                             , from_unixtime($"enqueuedTime").cast(TimestampType).as("enqueuedTime")
                             ).withWatermark("enqueuedTime", "1 minutes")

val df2 = df1.select(from_json(($"value"), schema).as("body")
                     , $"enqueuedTime")

val df3 = df2.select(
  $"enqueuedTime"
  , $"body.id".cast("integer")
  , $"body.latitude".cast("float")
  , $"body.longitude".cast("float")
  , $"body.tirePressure"
  , $"body.fuelEfficiencyPercentage"
  , $"body.weatherCondition"
)

val avgfuel = df3
  .groupBy(window($"enqueuedTime", "10 seconds"), $"weatherCondition" )    
  .agg(avg($"fuelEfficiencyPercentage") as "fuel_avg", stddev($"fuelEfficiencyPercentage") as "fuel_stddev")
  .select($"weatherCondition", $"fuel_avg")

val broadcasted = sc.broadcast(avgfuel)

val joined = df3.join(broadcasted.value, Seq("weatherCondition"))
                .filter($"fuelEfficiencyPercentage" > $"fuel_avg")

val streamingQuery1 = joined.writeStream.
      outputMode("append").
      trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds")).
      option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation).
      format("json").option("path", outputLocation).start()
```

This executes without errors and after a while results are starting to be written. I might be due to the broadcast of the aggregation result but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does it even work. AFAIK _Any kind of joins between two streaming Datasets is not yet supported_. Analyzing logic alone - if there is only one even in window the output is expected to be empty.

Comment: Events can't be DStream if you use Structured Streaming ;)

Comment: @user8371915 Stream-Stream joins are in 2.3

Comment: @T.Gawęda But it is not 2.3.

Comment: @user8371915 Yes, so it should probably fail, maybe it's not  throwing exception, but silently produces zero rows

Comment: That'd be an ugly bug, but it is plausible explanation. I am not motivate enough to check it - OP is not responsive. If you do, please let me know and I'll upvote accordingly :)

Comment: It doesn't throw any error, but indeed it doesn't produce any rows which I didn't understand why.

Comment: I probably miss-spoke about the DStream... 
It doesn't throw any error, but indeed it doesn't produce any rows which I didn't understand why.
Although I don't use Kafka I read this: https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/07%20Spark%20Streaming/13%20Joining%20DStreams.html and did the same for my case.
Do you have another suggestion on how to implement what I described?

Comment: Could you please post how you create `events`?

Comment: I posted a more complete code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Small investigation ;)

1. Events can't be a DStream, because you have option to use Dataset operations on it - it must be a Dataset
2. Stream-Stream joins are not allowed in Spark 2.2. I've tried to run your code with `events` as `rate` source and I get:

   > org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Inner join between two streaming DataFrames/Datasets is not supported;;
   >   Join Inner, (value#1L = eventValue#41L)
3. Result is quite unexpected - probably you used `read` instead of `readStream` and you didn't create a Streaming Dataset, but static. Change it to `readStream` and it will work - of course after upgrade to 2.3
4. Code - without comments above - is correct and should run correctly on Spark 2.3. Note that you must also change mode to `complete` instead of `append`, because you are doing aggregation

Comment: @user8371915 Spark is throwing an exception, so only explanation of this question is that wrong method was used to read data :)